# Changing data in datatable and it does not show in Grid

Tags: c#, datagrid, datagridview, datatable, dataset

I have a table adapter on a dataset which is linked to a datagrid with a binding source.

Now i have a column in my grid that is a checkbox which if clicked i change a value of another column in the grid.

So i do it on the cellvaluechanging event of the gridview and then I get the focused datarow in the datatable and change the other columns value but this does not come up immediately in the grid. I have to click out the cell before the other columns value is changed.

Is there a way i can call a method from the cell changing event so that the grid will go get its value from the datatable again?

Regards,
Cobus

Comment: Can you not just do something like MyDataTable.DataBind() to get it to rebind to the now modified data table or does that not work? not played with these for a while so not 100% sure this works (hence the comment and not answer).

Answer (score 0):

Just call the below for the columns that was changed.

GridView.RefreshRowCell()